# Turn off ALL optimization by Dalvik VM

Tags: android, performance, dalvik

So I'm trying to write some low-level code for Android, and my main concern is that I want to avoid ALL optimization by the JIT compiler (or anything else).  After doing some research, the best approach seems to be to:

1. write Java bytecode by hand
2. convert it to a dex file using the "dx" command
3. run it on the program using the "dalvikvm" command  (via adb shell) with the "-Xverify:none -Xdexopt:none" paramaters specified

My question is: will this in fact avoid ALL optimization?  The previous discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/Y-pzP9z6xLw makes me unsure, and I can't 100% convince myself by reading the docs.

Any confirmation one way or the other is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Have you tried writing byte code by hand? Do you mean use your own compiler? Writing byte code by hand is practically impossible.

Comment: Have you checked out NDK? https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: @njzk2, the idea is to make sure to stress the hardware in very specific ways, ie fill up the data/instruction cache, force so many cache misses, so many branches, etc.  so of course any optimization is going to introduce a lot of unknowns I'd like to avoid

Comment: @John you can use ASM, i am. doing so in my own eclipse builder that when using Log.+ methods you will see in the logcat additional merhod name and line number, see https://github.com/pskink/AndroidLoggerBuilder

Comment: @user1615903 thanks, this looks like a promising alternative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the instruction rewriting performed by `dexopt` cannot be disabled.  For example, accesses to `volatile long` fields must be handled differently from access to `long` fields, and the specialization is handled by replacing the field-get instruction with a different instruction.

The optimizations performed by `dexopt` take the form of instruction replacement, usually some sort of "quickening" that allows the VM to do a little less work.  All such optimizations are performed statically, ahead of time, not dynamically at run time, so you will get consistent behavior.  Enabling the `dexopt` optimizations doesn't introduce unknowns, it just changes from one set of knowns to a different set of knowns.

The biggest source of variation is going to be Dalvik's JIT compiler, which you can disable with `-Xint:fast`.  See [this slightly outdated doc](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/embedded-vm-control.html#execmode) for notes on how to configure this system-wide.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is as close as I'm going to get... also, using ASM plugin for Eclipse as suggested by @pskink above